# Subset and lagging list data structure

Tags: r, list

I have a list that is indexed like the following:

```
>list.stuff
[[1]]
[[1]]$vector
...
[[1]]$matrix
....
[[1]]$vector

[[2]]
null

[[3]]
[[3]]$vector
...
[[3]]$matrix
....
[[3]]$vector
.
.
.
```

Each segment in the list is indexed according to another vector of indexes:

```
>index.list
1, 3, 5, 10, 15
```

In `list.stuff`, only at each of the indexes 1,3,5,10,15 will there be 2 vectors and one matrix; everything else will be null like `[[2]]`. What I want to do is to lag like the `lag.xts` function so that whatever is stored in `[[1]]` will be pushed to `[[3]]` and the last one drops off. This also requires subsetting the list, if its possible. I was wondering if there exists some functions that handle list manipulation.

My thinking is that for `xts`, a time series can be extracted based on an index you supply:

```
xts.object[index,]  #returns the rows 1,3,5,10,15
```

From here I can lag it with:

```
lag.xts(xts.object[index,])
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks:

EDIT: Here is a reproducible example:

```
list.stuff<-list()
vec<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
vec2<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
mat<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),4,2)

list.vec.mat<-list(vec=vec,mat=mat,vec2=vec2)


ind<-c(2,4,6,8,10)
for(i in ind){
   list.stuff[[i]]<-list.vec.mat
}

slist<-list.stuff[ind]
list.stuff[ind]<-lapply(seq_along(slist),function(i) ifelse(i <= 1, NA, slist[[i-1]])) #lag list
```

The new lagged list only preserves one of the vectors rather than 2 vectors and list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an example list:

```
elist <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

The index:

```
index.list <- c(1, 3, 5)
```

Create a subset based on the index:

```
sublist <- elist[index.list]

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

The lag:

```
lag <- 1
```

Apply a lag of size `lag` to the list

```
newsublist <- lapply(seq_along(sublist),
                     function(i) if (i <= 1) NA else slist[[i-1]])

[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

*Note*. In its current implementation, the last command works for positive lags only.

Now, put the values back into the list `elist`:

```
elist[index.list] <- newsublist
```

The result:

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 3

[[6]]
[1] 6
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that after lagging i need to place the new list back to the original one with the original index

Comment: @user1234440 I extended my answer.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when each element in the list at each index stores 2 vectors and a matrix..., it seems to delete the original data

Comment: @user1234440 Please provide a *reproducible* example.

Comment: ok, i've just editted the question to include some code to generate the mini-sized problem i have. Thanks so much

Comment: @user1234440 Thanks for the example data. I modified my answer. The function `ifelse(...)` was replaced with an `if (...) ... else ...` sequence. Now it works with more complex lists too.

Answer (score 0):

Is using xts a requirement or just a thought for a possible solution? Have you tried:

```
list.stuff[ index.list[[[-1]] ]  <-
  list.stuff[ index.list[[-length(index.list)]] ]
```

Then, if required:

```
 list.stuff[ index.list[[[1]] ]  <- NULL # or some other value
```